# Display problems in some layers of Geoserver 2.3.1

Tags: postgis, geoserver, ubuntu, tomcat

I deleted Geoserver 2.2-SNAPSHOT and deleted tomcat6. Set tomcat7 (from ubuntu repository) and Geoserver 2.3.1. Rewrote his workspce (store, style ..), changing the owner to tomcat7. Some layers are not displayed. The database remains exact same (PostgreSQL9.2 / PostGIS1 .5)
Ubuntu server 12.04.

Style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.0.0">
    <sld:UserLayer>
        <sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
            <sld:FeatureTypeConstraint/>
        </sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
        <sld:UserStyle>
            <sld:Name>Продорожная полоса</sld:Name>
            <sld:Title/>
            <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
                <sld:Name>group 0</sld:Name>
                <sld:FeatureTypeName>Feature</sld:FeatureTypeName>
                <sld:SemanticTypeIdentifier>generic:geometry</sld:SemanticTypeIdentifier>
                <sld:SemanticTypeIdentifier>simple</sld:SemanticTypeIdentifier>
                <sld:Rule>
                    <sld:Name>default rule</sld:Name>
                    <sld:MinScaleDenominator>1.0</sld:MinScaleDenominator>
                    <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>50000.0</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Fill>
                            <sld:GraphicFill>
                                <sld:Graphic>
                                    <sld:Mark>
                                        <sld:WellKnownName>hatch</sld:WellKnownName>
                                        <sld:Fill/>
                                        <sld:Stroke>
                                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#808080</sld:CssParameter>
                                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">3.0</sld:CssParameter>
                                        </sld:Stroke>
                                    </sld:Mark>
                                    <sld:Size>3.0</sld:Size>
                                </sld:Graphic>
                            </sld:GraphicFill>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#D95F02</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.5</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Fill>
                        <sld:Stroke>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#FFFF00</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-dasharray">20.0</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Stroke>
                    </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                </sld:Rule>
            </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        </sld:UserStyle>
    </sld:UserLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Geoserver log

> org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Error attaching this
>   container for rendering: [MarkupContainer [Component id =
>   extraStyles]] at
>   org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1765)
>   at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3946) at
>   org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.form.palette.Palette.onBeforeRender(Palette.java:191)
>   at
>   org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:1071)
>   at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1105) at
>   org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1753)
>   at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3946) at
>   org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:1071)
>   at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1105) at
>   org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1753)
>   at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3946) at
>   org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:1071)
>   at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1105) at
>   org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1753)
>   at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3946) at
>   org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:1071)
>   at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1105) at
>   org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1753)
>   at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3946) at
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractRepeater.onBeforeRender(AbstractRepeater.java:151)
>   at
>   org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:1071)
>   at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1105) at
>   org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1753)
>   at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3946) at
>   org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:1071)
>   at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1105) at
>   org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1753)
>   at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3946) at
>   org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.tabs.TabbedPanel.onBeforeRender(TabbedPanel.java:244)
>   at
>   org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:1071)
>   at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1105) at
>   org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1753)
>   at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3946) at
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onBeforeRender(Form.java:2056)
>   at
>   org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:1071)
>   at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1105) at
>   org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1753)
>   at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3946) at
>   org.apache.wicket.Page.onBeforeRender(Page.java:1531) at
>   org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:1071)
>   at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1105) at
>   org.apache.wicket.Component.prepareForRender(Component.java:2292) at
>   org.apache.wicket.Page.prepareForRender(Page.java:1521) at
>   org.apache.wicket.Component.prepareForRender(Component.java:2329) at
>   org.apache.wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:892) at
>   org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebRequestCycle.redirectTo(WebRequestCycle.java:186)
>   at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.PageRequestTarget.respond(PageRequestTarget.java:58)
>   at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.respond(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:105)
>   at
>   org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1258)
>   at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329) at
>   org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1436) at
>   org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545) at
>   org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:484)
>   at
>   org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doPost(WicketServlet.java:160)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:159)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:27)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:74)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:45)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:49)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   org.vfny.geoserver.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:115)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:46)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:103)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:75)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:47)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>   at
>   com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat70AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat70AgentValve.java:38)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.geoserver.wms.web.publish.StyleNameRenderer.getIdValue(StyleNameRenderer.java:21)
>   at
>   org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.form.palette.component.Recorder.initIds(Recorder.java:116)
>   at
>   org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.form.palette.component.Recorder.onBeforeRender(Recorder.java:87)
>   at
>   org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:1071)
>   at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1105) at
>   org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1753)
>   ... 140 more

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it!
If you layer in the Publishing tab, in the list of "Selected Styles" have records of styles, then we get this error.
I deleted the source Geoserver 2.2 these records and to save the layer. Moved workspace to a new Geoserver abd can see all the layers!

[image]